# Is it possible to change a constant variable value when using upgradeable pattern and deploying a new version?

Tags: openzeppelin, proxy-contracts, upgrading, contract-upgrading, constant

The title is pretty self explanatory.

Let's say I have a contract where I defined a constant variable and this contract is using some upgradeable pattern. When I deploy a new version of the contract, theoretically I can overwrite the constant's value, since that is baked into the bytecode.

**Example:**

1. First version of the contract:

```js
contract MyUpgradeableContract {

   uint256 public constant ZERO_TO_BE_ONE = 0;

}
```

2. Contract after upgrade:

```js
contract MyUpgradeableContract {

   uint256 public constant ZERO_TO_BE_ONE = 1;

}
```

Is this allowed in solidity with upgradeable pattern?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can override the constant, as the value doesn't occupy any storage slot, but exists in the runtime bytecode, which is deployed in the new contract.